# Using modal React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use modal in react-native. What I would to obtain is a message in which there are 3 buttons that the user can 
click (every button has a property) and obviously when you click in this button the modal message should disappear.

This is a part of my code where I use modal, but I doesn't work. Basically when I click on a button I would to go to the removeMonitoring function passing (this.feedback)

> I receive the error: Warning: Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure
>   function of props and state.

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'

constructor(props){
    this.state={
    visibleModal: null, 
    }
}

_renderButton = (text, onPress) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={activity.buttonModal}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  _renderModalContent = () => (
    <View style={activity.modalContent}>
      <Text>Choose one:</Text>
      <Button 
        title="Normal"
        onPress={() => this.setState({ visibleModal: null}), this.removeMonitoring((this.feedback = "N"))}
      />
    </View>
  );

  showLoader(){
  if(....){
        this.setState({ visibleModal: 1 })
    }
  }

  render(){
  return(
  <View>
        <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 1}>
            {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
 <TouchableOpacity
                style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
                onPress={() => this.showLoader()}
              >
                <Text style={style.buttonText}>Stop</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  )
  }
```

Comment: The problem is the `onPress` in your `_renderModalContent`. The short form of `() => statement` only works for **one** statement. If you have multiple statements, you need to wrap them in `{...}`

Comment: Oh I'm a monkey :D Thank you